Getting error while installing the Identity IQ

FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/identityiq]]]

am trying to open SailPoint page but getting 404 error

Most often, if IdentityIQ fails to start, there is a problem with the database connection. Try starting the IdentityIQ console, first. This typically provides more detailed error information.
Also, check permissions on the files. If the Tomcat service account is unable to read files, like iiq.properties, it will not be able to start.
